# Discrepancy in GitVersion between local clone and repo checked out by Azure Pipelines

Tags: git, azure-pipelines, gitversion

I have a branch in a repository for which GitVersion when run locally on a fresh clone returns one version (*1.5.0-netcore1*), but when running GitVersion on Azure Pipelines on the same branch it returns *another* version (*1.4.1-netcore1*). (Only the minor and patch versions are different in the entire output from `gitversion`).

I did setup a local agent, so I have the repository in a local folder on my computer as checked out by Azure Pipelines and the discrepancy is the same when I run `gitversion` in that folder as opposed to the one I cloned using `git clone`.

The results of running `git tag` and `git branch` on the two folders are the same, listing all branches and tags.

```
> git tag
1.3.0
1.4.0
```

```
> git branch
  archive/1.0
  archive/1.1
  archive/1.2
  develop
* feature/netcore
  gh-pages
  master
```

What could be different between those two clones of the same repository, and what can I do to make GitVersion behave the same?

For reference, the repository in question is https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaVSS/tree/feature/netcore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested gitversion against your repository. I can reproduce the same discrepancy.

The discrepancy is fixed by **git checkout master branch** for the local folder your cloned using `git clone`. 
I found `git clone` your repository did not check out master automatically to local folder. It has to be done manually.However cloning using azure pipeline and visual studio will check out master as default.

It seems that gitversion uses some metadata of master branch to calculate the version.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)  This was driving me crazy. Never occurred to me that checking out a branch would make a difference.